# Как работает асинхронность цикле?

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, как работают асинхронные вызовы  цикле

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
setTimeout(()=>console.log(i),5000)
}
```

Непонятно почему значения i не выводятся каждые 5 секунд,а выводятся все цифры от 0 до 9 спустя 5 секунд.

Answer (score 3):

Вы в плотном цикле (сразу) заказываете десять отложенных действий, которые должны произойти через пять секунд. Вот они все и происходят через пять секунд.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000 * (i + 1))
}
```

Comment: Простите, не могли бы Вы объяснить почему так! Не понимаю..

Comment: @Domosed_007 Что "так"? Вам придется постараться сформулировать точнее, *что* Вы не понимаете в тексте ответа.

Comment: Дело в том, что только начал разбираться с асинхрощиной в js, и непонятно почему setTimeout(()=>console.log(i),5000) - не работает, а так: setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 1000 * (i + 1)) - работает

Comment: @Domosed_007 Потому что `i` увеличивается с каждой итерацией цикла. Первое действие должно произойти через одну секунду (`1000 * (0 + 1)`), второе - через две  (`1000 * (1 + 1)`), и так далее.